# No data in area chart

Tags: d3.js

I have an area chart I am using from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195 with a simple modification of using json data.
The json is returned without issue, and no other errors present themselves, however, no chart is displayed.
The x and y axes are displayed, but no chart.

jsfiddle.net/oqc19yff/

Any pointers welcome.
Kev

Comment: could you also post your data

Comment: [{"id":"1","event_time":"Mon 14:00","total":"16523175"},{"id":"2","event_time":"Mon 15:00","total":"16192436"},{"id":"3","event_time":"Mon 16:00","total":"16129454"},{"id":"4","event_time":"Mon 17:00","total":"16500333"},{"id":"5","event_time":"Mon 18:00","total":"17186756"},{"id":"6","event_time":"Mon 19:00","total":"20019621"}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.event_time; }));
```

Reason:

Because x is an ordinal scale.

Instead it should have been:

```
//declare a variable array
var k = [];
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.event_time = d.event_time;
    d.total = +d.total;
    k.push(d.event_time);//in that array store all the event_time
});
```

Now set that array as domain of x.

```
  x.domain(k);
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BtYMctJDhTeRZPRs5mdY?p=preview)